# How to list all the users of a team using asana api?

Tags: asana

I am developing an application using the Asana API. As a part of which I need to display all the members of a team in an organization. When I use /organizations/organization-id/teams I get a listing of all the teams(team id and team name) and if i use /teams/team-id I get the team id, team name, and organization details(id and name).

How do I access the team members?

Answer (score 0):

Try `/teams/{team-id}/users` - not yet publicly documented, but I suspect the endpoint won't change much before we publicly document it.